# What's the benefit of that escape in the reflect package

Tags: go, reflection, implementation

```golang
// reflect/value.go

func ValueOf(i interface{}) Value {
    if i == nil {
        return Value{}
    }

    // TODO: Maybe allow contents of a Value to live on the stack.
    // For now we make the contents always escape to the heap. It
    // makes life easier in a few places (see chanrecv/mapassign
    // comment below).
    escapes(i)
```

The code above is the source code of `Value.go` in golang, and the comment above the `escapes(i)` shows that each time we call the `ValueOf` function, the `i` will escape to the heap, that's why? Namely, how to explain the *It makes life easier in a few places*?

Comment: `(see chanrecv/mapassign comment below)` what do they say?

Comment: @tkausl ```// Note: some of the noescape annotations below are technically a lie,
// but safe in the context of this package. Functions like chansend
// and mapassign don't escape the referent, but may escape anything
// the referent points to (they do shallow copies of the referent).
// It is safe in this package because the referent may only point
// to something a Value may point to, and that is always in the heap
// (due to the escapes() call in ValueOf).```

Comment: @tkausl I have no idea for the meaning of that comment for `chanrecv/mapassign`

Answer (score 0):

I am still learning go, so I can't describe more, that's why a community wiki answer. But here's what excerpted note says (note above the chanrecv function):

> Note: some of the noescape annotations below are technically a lie,
> but safe in the context of this package. Functions like chansend
> and mapassign don't escape the referent, but may escape anything
> the referent points to (they do shallow copies of the referent).
> It is safe in this package because the referent may only point
> to something a Value may point to, and that is always in the heap
> (due to the escapes() call in ValueOf).

Also see:

```
// Dummy annotation marking that the value x escapes,
// for use in cases where the reflect code is so clever that
// the compiler cannot follow.
func escapes(x interface{}) {
    if dummy.b {
        dummy.x = x
    }
}

var dummy struct {
    b bool
    x interface{}
}
```

I hope, this will be helpful.

Comment: Thx at first. *It is safe in this package because the referent may only point to something a Value may point to, and that is always in the heap*. What's your point to this words? what is the meaning of  the `safe` in this word? GC safe? Reference safe?

Comment: @SimonHu That's not my word. That's the note found on the code, on same file. I just tried to help. :)